# Adding SVN version info to source code (CMAKE)

Tags: svn, cmake, versioning

I have this code in my CMake file to get SVN version info and push it into a define that my project can use:

```
   find_package(Subversion)
   if(SUBVERSION_FOUND)
     Subversion_WC_INFO(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} MyProj)
     target_compile_definitions(MyProj PUBLIC "-DSVN_RC=${MyProj_WC_REVISION}" )
   endif(SUBVERSION_FOUND)
```

This uses a macro found in the default CMake distribution.  This is effectively what the macro does:

```
  macro(Subversion_WC_INFO dir prefix)

    execute_process(COMMAND ${Subversion_SVN_EXECUTABLE} info ${dir}
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${prefix}_WC_INFO
      ERROR_VARIABLE Subversion_svn_info_error
      RESULT_VARIABLE Subversion_svn_info_result
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

    if(NOT ${Subversion_svn_info_result} EQUAL 0)
      message(SEND_ERROR "Command \"${Subversion_SVN_EXECUTABLE} info ${dir}\" failed with output:\n${Subversion_svn_info_error}")
    endif()

  endmacro()
```

My problem is that this code fails.  The output of my configuration looks like this:

```
CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw32/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindSubversion.cmake:99 (message):
  Command "C:/msys64/usr/bin/svn.exe info
  C:/msys64/home/stew/proj"
  failed with output:

  svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/stew/proj/build/C:/msys64/home/stew/proj/' was not found.

  svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist
```

I think the problem is my msys environment which is kind of a fake-root environment.  `svn info /home/stew/proj` works while `svn info c:/msys64/home/stew/proj` doesn't work.  `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` gives me the windows path which is a problem for svn.  Is there a way to translate the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} output in Windows format into the fakeroot format?  If not, is there a way to force SVN to accept the other path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. My solution was:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} svnversion -n OUTPUT_VARIABLE SVN_COMMIT)
```

The `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` bit runs what follows as a command in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: Make sure your path is set up correctly. `find_package(Subversion)` failed for me (running through QtCreator) so I had to set the path manually.